# How to handle non-tidy data in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

First I have to say that I am fairly new to Python and Pandas but I want to use them much more in the future therefore I am experimenting with it. Due to my job I used Excel a lot and often ran into the problem that data (rows) has their attributes (column(s)) but sometimes some data (row) can have a third dimension. Here is a simple Pandas dataframe example to show what I mean:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data={"obs":[["test1","test2"],"test1"],
                   "result":[[101,103],200]},index=["subj1","subj2"])
df

                  obs      result
subj1  [test1, test2]  [101, 103]
subj2           test1         200
```

How do you deal with that generally? I read the term "tidy data" where each value should get it's own cell. Should I add columns => obs1,obs2,result1,result2 or add rows for each deviant subject like: subj1_1, subj1_2 what would make more sense for as the attributes (columns) stay the same. Can make multiindexes make sense here? I read a little bit about it but I don't know enough yet to use them efficiently. I was searching for that topic but nothing helped me concrete.

Comment: I am afraid this is a too broad question here. The common ways depend on the real context. Anyway asking for external ressources is explicitely off topic here.

Comment: pretty sure that should just be three rows, with subject1 repeated twice.  there are lots of [articles](http://shzhangji.com/blog/2017/09/30/pandas-and-tidy-data/) on how pandas helps get you there.  this is closely related to "database normalisation" where there's lots of related literature

Comment: Yes I also thought it might be too broad but didn't know how I can write it more explicit. I will remove external resource question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your example I think that the subj isn't a good index. I would *recommend* to use numerical incremental index or multi index. It's easier to handle in the future. Consider an example:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(
    data={
        'subj':["subj1","subj1", "subj1", "subj1", "subj2", "subj2","subj2", "subj2", "subj3", "subj3"] ,
        "obs":["test1","test2","test2","test1",'test1','test1','test2','test2','test1','test2'],
        "result":[101,103,105,110, 203,159,193,285,400,543] 
    }
)
df
    subj    obs  result
0  subj1  test1     101
1  subj1  test2     103
2  subj1  test2     105
3  subj1  test1     110
4  subj2  test1     203
5  subj2  test1     159
6  subj2  test2     193
7  subj2  test2     285
8  subj3  test1     400
9  subj3  test2     543
```

Let's consider that you want to calculate mean result for *each unique* subj. Since all data points have their own row you can use panda's functions: [groupby](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.mean.html) and [mean](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.mean.html).

```
df.groupby('subj').mean()
       result
subj         
subj1  104.75
subj2  210.00
subj3  471.50
```

or if you want to calculate mean for each subj and obj

```
df.groupby(['subj','obs']).mean()
             result
subj  obs          
subj1 test1   105.5
      test2   104.0
subj2 test1   181.0
      test2   239.0
subj3 test1   400.0
      test2   543.0
```

If you encounter data points in lists after importing data from excel - I would *recommend* to write a function that will make n rows out of 1 and [apply](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html) it across 1 axis

Hope that helps!

Comment: so much useless and irrelevant information in regards with the question

Comment: @Arkady: thanks for your answer. I will accept your answer as your statement makes sense to create multiple rows whenever lists are the column values.